# Reversing a list then adding new item

Tags: f#

I am trying to learn F#, and I'm trying to create some simple functions as part of this learning.

I have created a function that adds an item to a list then reverses the result. This works very nicely in the F# interactive window in Visual Studio

```
let addThenReverse n list =
match list with
| [] -> []
| _ -> n::list |> List.rev

addThenReverse 0 [1;2;3]   //results in [3; 2; 1; 0]
```

But I'm having difficulty with writing a function that would reverse a list then add an item to it.

```
let reverseThenAdd n list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | _ -> List.rev list |> n::list

reverseThenAdd 9 [1;2;3]  //desired result [3; 2; 1; 9]
```

**EDIT** 
The desired result for the above should be **[9; 3; 2; 1]**. Well done to those who spotted this!

This second function does not compile and I receive the warning 'This expression was expected to have type 'a list -> 'b list but here has type 'c list'

Any variants I try seem to result other compilation errors. I assume (but don't know how) that I need to use the new list created as a result of 'List.rev list', perhaps by assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Surely the result of `addThenReverse 0 []` should be `[0]`?

Comment: @RobLyndon I'd set off with grander plans than merely turning a list around and adding a new item, but as that got progressively more difficult I had to curb my enthusiam and set my sights lower. That's why the logic with the empty list looks a little odd. Many thanks for your answer and comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing the reversed list to a concatenation expression, and that throws off the compiler. You should do:

```
let reverseThenAdd n list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | _ -> n :: (List.rev list)

reverseThenAdd 9 [1;2;3]  //desired result [3;2;1;9]
```

which means that you are adding `n` to the list resulting from `(List.rev list)`

Comment: I like this answer since it makes it easier for my 'C#' conditioned brain to understand. The parentheses say do this bit first, then add to the reversed list. I've marked this as my accepted answer since it directly answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little confused by your desired results. Luiso has a version of your code that will fix the compiler, but it won't fit your desired result. With

```
let reverseThenAdd n list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | _ -> n :: (List.rev list)

reverseThenAdd 9 [1;2;3]  //desired result [3; 2; 1; 9]
```

the actual result will be `[9; 3; 2; 1]`. If the comment is a typo, and that is in fact your desired result, then Luiso's answer works. Otherwise, there is no material difference between `addThenReverse` and `reverseThenAdd`, because "add" means something different (appending and prepending) in each case.

Note that I think in both cases, the first case should be

```
| [] -> [n]
```

rather than

```
| [] -> []
```

In fact, I don't think you need the match statement at all. I think the mathematically correct formulation would be:

```
let addThenReverse n list = n::list |> List.rev
let reverseThenAdd n list = n::(list |> List.rev)
```

Then you would have

```
addThenReverse 0 [] // result: [0]
reverseThenAdd 0 [] // result: [0]
addThenReverse 9 [1; 2; 3] // result: [3; 2; 1; 9]
reverseThenAdd 9 [1; 2; 3] // result: [9; 3; 2; 1]
```

**ADDENDUM**

I'm a fan of expressive code. As elegant as F# is, it is still possible to write code that obscures what you're actually trying to do. The code above works, but you can make it more expressive, and learn a bit more about how the language works, by using the composition operator:

```
let add n list = n::list
let reverse = List.rev
let addThenReverse n = add n >> reverse
let reverseThenAdd n = reverse >> add n
```

This gives the same results as before, but it expresses what you're doing more clearly. True to the spirit of functional programming, you're telling the compiler *what* to do, rather than *how* to do it.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank you for this comment and its useful pointers. I was really torn between accepting your answer and Luiso's. I've accepted Luiso's, purely on the grounds that it answered my question directly. I would have liked to accept both since your answer points me towards greater learning in F#. I've voted up both yours and Luiso's answer.

Comment: No worries Daniel. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
let reverseThenAdd n list = List.rev list @ [n]
```